# Reflecting Brownian motion in disk

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, conformal-maps

What is the transition density function of a reflecting Brownian motion in $\mathbb D \overset{\mathrm{def}}= \{z \in \mathbb C : \lvert z\rvert < 1\}$ and how to compute it?

The transition density function of a reflecting Brownian motion in $\mathbb H$ can be easily seen to be $p_t(x, y) + p_t(x, \overline y)$, where $p_t$ is the transition density function of a standard $2$-dimensional Brownian motion. We also know that if $\varphi$ is a conformal mapping from $\mathbb H$ onto $\mathbb D$, then the image of a reflecting Brownian motion in $\mathbb H$ via $\varphi$ reparameterized to have quadratic variation $t$ is a reflecting Brownian motion in $\mathbb D$. Can we use these facts to compute the transition density function of a reflecting Brownian motion in $\mathbb D$?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in references here [Reference for representation of heat equation with Neumann boundary condition on smooth domain using reflected Brownian motion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435637/reference-for-representation-of-heat-equation-with-neumann-boundary-condition-on),

you are looking for the solution of the following Neumann-problem:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}\partial_{t}p(t,r,\theta)=\Delta_{r,\theta}p(t,r,\theta)\\\partial_{r}p(t,r,\theta)|_{r=1}=0\end{matrix}\right..$$

We follow [MULTI-DIMENSIONAL PDES: SEPARABLE PROBLEMS](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ejtwong/math551-2019/lectures/Separable1_PDEs_in_nd.pdf). By separating $p(t,r,\theta)=T(t)R(r)g(\theta)$, we obtain an eigenvalue problem

$$\frac{1}{rR}(rR')'+\frac{\mu^2}{r^{2}}R=\lambda R,\partial_{r}R(r)|_{r=1}=0,R~\text{ bounded }$$

for some constants $\mu,\lambda$. This can be written as the Bessel’s equation

$$y''+\frac{1}{\xi}y+(1-\frac{m^{2}}{\xi})y(\xi)=0$$

for $y(\xi)=y(r\sqrt{\lambda})=R(r)$ and $\mu^{2}=m^{2}$, and the solution is

$$y(\xi)=aJ_{m}(\xi)+bY_{m}(\xi),$$

for the regular/modified Bessel functions $J,Y$. Since $R$ is bounded we don't get the $Y_{m}$. And since

$$\partial_{r}R|_{r=1}=0\Rightarrow \partial_{r}J_{m}(\sqrt{\lambda})=0.$$

The critical points of $J_{m}$ are similarly some increasing sequence $\gamma_{m}$ (Eg. see "Some recent results on the zeros of Bessel functions and orthogonal polynomials".).

So in summary we have

$$p(t,r,\theta)=\sum_{m\geq 0}\sum_{n\geq 1}e^{-\gamma_{m,n}t}J_{m}(r\sqrt{\gamma_{m,n}})(a_{m,n}\cos(m\theta)+b_{m,n}\sin(m\theta)).$$

In terms of using conformal invariance see the articles [TRAPS FOR REFLECTED BROWNIAN MOTION](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emarshall/preprints/traps/trapspre.pdf) on page 17 and ["Uniqueness for reflecting Brownian motion in lip domains"](http://www.numdam.org/item/10.1016/j.anihpb.2004.06.001.pdf).